# Better frame rate drawing bitmaps in a Canvas (Part 2)?

Tags: android, animation, opengl-es, bitmap, live-wallpaper

Here's what I'm trying to do: I'm trying to load a sequence of bitmaps to display an animation. That means that I need to have a descent fps (24 fps). I need to load no more than 10 seconds of animations or about 300 bitmaps. And since it's a live wallpaper I'm limited to manually drawing each frame.

Here's what I tried so far:

1. The obvious strategy: load each bitmap each frame and draw it. This is slow.
2. Use caching. I put the bitmap loading in a seperate thread. A cache of about 20 bitmaps   continously load in the background. However, I still get poor performance (about 10 fps). The culprit is  slow bitmap loading.
3. I was going to try using OpenGL but then I realized that even with OpenGL, the slow bitmap loading will still be a problem. Right? (Or am I wrong?)

So what other strategies can I use?

Here's what I had in mind: if I use openGL, I can use smaller bitmaps (because it gives better scaling). Perhaps then I can have a bigger cache - say perhaps 3 seconds. With a larger cache, the slow bitmap loading will not be a problem, right?

Any other strategies?

---

Oh and this is my current bitmap loading function:

```
void loadNthBitmap(int i, int n) {
    try {
    buf = new 
        BufferedInputStream(assets.
                open(folder+"/"
                     +imageList[n])
                );
    tmpBitmap = BitmapFactory.
        decodeStream(buf);
    rbitmap[i] = Bitmap.createBitmap
        (tmpBitmap,
         0,0,imageWidth,imageHeight,
         transMatrix,false);
    }
    catch(IOException e) {}
}
```

where `imageList` is pre-defined list of assets and `transMatrix` is a rotation and scaling matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do (i.e. full-frame animation) is not easy.  Almost all Android animation  (from the Lunar Lander example in the SDK to Angry Birds) consists of moving small sprites on a relatively static background.

The "obvious" solution to your problem would be to turn your animation into an mpeg and then decode it as a video live wallpaper, replicating the approach that this guy took here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=804720 (alternative link http://android.ccpcreations.com/vlw/)

Comment: That's a start. Following RockPlayer's approach, I'm getting about 10 fps for my test video. This approach uses FFmpeg, NDK, and OpenGL textures. Probably, I should use frame buffers.

Comment: @u-avalos Thanks for the accept/upvote.  You are obviously a very serious coder.  Good luck with your project. :-)

Comment: @u-avalos In the FAQ here http://android.ccpcreations.com/vlw/vlw-faq , the VLW guy claims ~24 fps @ 480x854, and has some codec recommendations.